# How to calculate the sum of very large ranges in Python in 0.1 seconds?

Tags: python, sum, range, addition

I was given a task in Python to calculate a sum in a range from 1 to N, where N can be up 10**25, with the program execution time not taking more than 0.1 seconds, which I failed and now to try to understand how it should've been done. Preferably a for loop should be used for this (not explicitly stated in the task, but hinted at).

Tried many things: from a basic for loop to `reduce(add, range(0, 10**25))` to `sum(range(1,10**25)`, but none of them surely work fast enough. What is such an efficient way to fit such a large sum calculation in 0.1 seconds?

P.S Thank you for all the responses, somehow did not see the easiest way possible.

Comment: If it's just a range, you should use a mathematical formula rather than brute forcing it. Just calculate the mean and multiply by the number of numbers. `(e0 + ef)/2 * num`

Answer (score 3):

The sum of the integers from `1` to `N` is `N * (N + 1) / 2`.

```py
n = 10 ** 25
res = n * (n + 1) // 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Because there is a mathematical formula for 1+2+...+n, this should work:

```py
n = 10 ** 25
result = (n * (n + 1)) / 2
```